# Quais as diferenças entre classes/membros Friend e Static?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Quais as diferenças entre classes e variáveis membro `friend` e `static` dentro da definição de uma classe, inclusive suas aplicações. Sei apenas que membros da classe `static` pertencem à classe e não ao objeto. Membros da classe `friend` pertencem ao objeto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um membro amigo não pertence a uma instância do objeto, ou seja, não pode acessar pelo `this`, o acesso se dará através de um parâmetro explicitamente declarado.

O membro amigo apenas delega o acesso aos membros privados e protegidos à uma função ou classe, portanto o código apenas declara que uma função ou uma classe específica pode acessar seus membros "internos" como se aquilo fosse parte da classe, mesmo estando fora.

Então se você declara que uma função `teste(MeuTipo objeto&)` como `friend` dentro da classe `MeuTipo`, quando essa função for definida em outro lugar, o parâmetro `objeto` poderá acessar todos os membro da classe `MeuTipo`, mesmo os `private` e `protected`.

Obviamente que se a função não recebe um parâmetro com o tipo específico, não faz muito sentido.

De uma certa forma podemos dizer que o membro `friend` é estático e será definido em algum outro lugar fora da classe.

Lembra um pouco um método puramente virtual, mas o mecanismo é completamente diferente. A definição do membro não será feito por polimorfismo ou herança, pelo contrário.

Lembrando que existe a declaração da classe amiga também. Essa declaração diz que toda a classe amiga poderá acessar os membros desta classe. Obviamente isso só poderá ocorrer por uma referência explícita a esta classe.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado! c: